How can I remove a recent skim coat from concrete walls?
I just had my flat skimmed. The plasterer did a poor job and on reflection decorators could have sorted it as it was cracks and electrical chasing but it wasn’t that bad. I want it off my walls.
How would I do this? Wet it and scrape? It’s on solid concrete walls. Decorator is telling me it’s fine but I’m in a muddle about it. Thanks

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Whether something is "wild" is not for us to assess. We answer how-to questions here. Please take the [tour] and see [ask], then revise further to clarify your question. It's not apparent what aspect of the job is "poor", so it's difficult to give good answers. It's unlikely that complete removal of all material is the right solution.

Pictures would help.

It's also not clear why you wouldn't expect the tradesperson to rectify a poor job. Have you discussed it with the person?

You paid a professional to do a skim coat job. The professional decorators, that we must assume you also hired, say the result is "fine".  So one would have to assume that the dissatisfaction with the result is a personal preference and not a question of a job done incorrectly.   The quickest way to rectify this is to relay your desires to the decorator and request that the job be modified to your liking.

Sledgehammer should do it. Have fun.
